# PSPDFKit- Table of contents, bug?

Tags: cocoa-touch, pspdfkit

I'm thinking of buying PSPDFkit for my company, I think is just perfect for what we need here, I'm not an expert developer but i was trying different things these days to see how it works, everything great and it does even more than i need, but there's a problem on the TABLE OF CONTENTS menu, the automatic searching block cell, when it reads the PDF, it detects almost everything just fine, alphabetically but only till the word "E" after then nothing appears...i mean, it reads all the pages of a pdf book and detects contents and chapters but only till "E" the rest of pages alphabetically after "e" don't show up in the scrolling bar... so i would like to know if this is a restriction cos is the demo version, or is a bug ??? any idea? i did try many things, like , changing the fonts on my pdf, labeling every page with numbers, letters to make it easy to find, but it does't go beyond "E" ... before I buy it i really need to know how to make this work fine, as the works i'm going to make is like a kind of catalog with lots of pages and chapters, so this function is fundamental for me. I appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found what was happening, it wasn't a bug or anything like that. The solution was quite easy, i simply edited my pdf by adding manually the index ( sons, daughters, uncles etc... ) to it , then added normally to the project and it works just perfect. I hope this helps incase is there anyone out there with the same issue. cheers.